# Counting the probability of # of boxes having different colors of balls

Tags: probability

Disclosure first, this is a homework problem said to be particularly difficult.

> There are 300 white balls and 100 black balls randomly distributed into 200 boxes, with each box containing two balls. Let $X$ be the number of boxes with two different balls inside. Find $E(X)$.

I have at present figured this out and planning to sum it up, but I'm not even sure if this is right:

$$
P(X = x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{C^x_{200}C^x_{100}C^\frac{100-x}{2}_{200-x}}{C^{100}_{400}}, & \textrm{if } x \textrm{ is even}\\
0, & \textrm{if } x \textrm{ is odd}
\end{cases}
$$

I'm thinking of this: It's apparent that $X$ must be even. Now when $X = x$, there are $x$ boxes with different balls, and $100 - x$ boxes with two black balls, and $200 - x$ boxes with two white balls. After putting $x$ balls into each "box with different balls", the remaining $100 - x$ black balls should be distributed into $\frac{100 - x}{2}$ "boxes with two same balls".

Is my idea correct? Can anyone guide me on the right track?

Comment: Have you considered using linearity of expectation?  The expected number of boxes with two different balls inside is $100$ times the probability that a box contains two different balls.

Comment: @saulspatz My concerns are 1. the total number of balls is limited and 2. why 100 times not 200 times?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo and it's too late to edit.  It should be $200$ balls.  I don't understand your concern number $1$.

Comment: @saulspatz What the outcome of the 1st box is has an impact on the 2nd box, and so on.

Comment: I'll write answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fo $k=1,\dots,200$ let $X_k$ be a random variable which takes the value $1$ if box $k$ has two different color balls and the $0$ if it has two balls of the same color, so that $X=\sum_{k=1}^{200}X_k.$  We are asked for

$$E\left(\sum_{k=1}^{200}X_k\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{200}E(X_k)=200p,$$ where $p$ is the probability that box $k$ contains two balls of different colors, and the first equality is by linearity of expectation.

Recall that linearity of expectation holds even when the random variables are dependent.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've worked this out on my own following my original idea, and verified the result against your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I've worked out and the result is the same as @saulspatz's answer so I'm thinking it's correct.

The expression is:

$$
P(X = x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{2^xC^x_{200}C^\frac{100 - x}{2}_{200 - x}}{C^{100}_{400}}, & \textrm{if } x \textrm{ is even}\\
0, & \textrm{if } x \textrm{ is odd}
\end{cases}
$$

The explanation:

Consider $C^{100}_{400}$ as the number of ways to align all balls in a row. Now there are $x$ boxes with two different balls, so there are $2^x$ ways of arranging balls in those boxes (each box can have black-white or white-black). Then in the remaining $200 - x$ boxes, $\frac{100 - x}{2}$ of them contains two black balls, and the rest are all white balls. Arrange these loaded boxes up in a row, we get a unique layout of arrangement of balls in a row.

To prove this, using Mathematica, one can easily verify that:

$$\sum_{x=0}^{100} P(X = x) = 1$$
$$\sum_{x=0}^{100} x \cdot P(X = x) = \color{red}{\textrm{a}}\color{orange}{\textrm{n}}\color{green}{\textrm{s}}\color{cyan}{\textrm{w}}\color{blue}{\textrm{e}}\color{purple}{\textrm{r}}$$

Comment: Your approach is certainly correct.  Simplifying the answer without use of a computer algebra system seems challenging, though.  (This isn't a criticism; I'm all for the use of CAS.)